# PHPSessionId - where is it stored in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I have an IE10 on my windows machine, when I navigate to a site it allocates me a PHP session id.

I am trying to find out where this session ID is stored but cannot find it. I am looking in two different places:

1. In memory - if I close the IE process and reopen it, I can still log on using the same session ID so it isn't the case
2. If i look in the cookies folder in IE I cannot see any cookie from that site

Any ideas where is this session ID stored?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Internet Options->General, then under Browsing History, click Settings.  Click View files to open the folder.  Cookies are stored in text files there based on the domain.

If you don't see it there, it's probably stored in a separate area such as Flash data or localStorage (in which case, not exactly cookies).

All that aside, what's the point of going through all that effort?  If you want to delete a cookie, there are much easier ways.

Answer (score 0):

I was already looking in the trivial places for cookies and could not find the session ID. 
The point here is not to delete the session ID, the point here is to understand where it is stored for Appsec purposes.